# Copy the superclass part of a subclass object

Tags: matlab, inheritance, copy-constructor

Say I have

```
classdef A < matlab.mixin.Copyable & matlab.mixin.Heterogeneous
.
.
classdef B < A
.
.
classdef C < A
```

What I want is to be able to construct an instance of C based on an instance of B, by copying the A-properties only. And I'd rather not implement a custom `mycopy` method, because then I would need to update it every time I add a property to A.

I tried modifying `copyElement()` of B so that it only calls the `copyElement()` of A, but (unsurprisingly) still returned an object of class B.

Note that my "conversion" is in the opposite direction of most questions "out there" (SO and Google), which copy from superclass to subclass. Maybe for some conceptual reason what I want is a bad idea. Nevertheless, As it says [here](http://www.mathworks.se/help/matlab/matlab_oop/modifying-superclass-methods-and-properties.html)

> An important concept in class design is that a subclass object is also an object of its superclass.

and I know I can construct a subclass object from a superclass one.

Comment: Did you try constructing C from version of B that has been typecast to type A?

Comment: Using cast or typecast? They don't support other classes than built-in ones. http://www.mathworks.se/help/matlab/ref/typecast.html
http://www.mathworks.se/help/matlab/ref/cast.html

Answer (score 2):

(I recognize this is a very old post, but since I didn't see a good solution anywhere, I thought I'd post my solution in case it helps someone.)

NOTE: If you need to do this such that 'C' is not a subclass of 'B', then skip the first version of 'C' and check out the 'C2' class at the end.

I worked out this solution for copying data for complex subclasses of complex superclasses, and thought I'd share it.  It works for classes with many hidden properties.  I modified it to inlcude your sub-subclass and your specific question, so I hope it helps in both cases.

So if you define a simple superclass 'A':

```
classdef A
    properties
        propA
        propB
    end
    properties (Dependent)
        dependentProp;
    end
    methods
        function val=get.dependentProp(obj)
            val='dependent value';
        end
    end
end
```

You can then provide a constructor for a subclass 'B' to find and copy all independent variables (check out [getting information about properties](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_oop/getting-information-about-properties.html) to understand more about the '?' operator and meta data for properties):

```
classdef B < A
    properties
        propI
        propJ
    end
    methods
        function obj=B(varargin)
            obj@A();
            if nargin==1
                if isa(varargin{1},'A')
                    meta=?A;
                    dependent=[meta.PropertyList.Dependent];
                    props={meta.PropertyList.Name};
                    for pname=props(~dependent)
                        eval(['obj.' pname{1} '=varargin{1}.' pname{1} ';']);
                    end
                end
            end
        end
    end
end
```

By doing this, you can create a object of type 'B' from an object of class 'A':

```
objA=A;
objA.propA='valA';
objA.propB='valB'
objB=B(objA)
```

This results in the following output:

```
objA = 

  A with properties:

        propA: 'valA'
        propB: 'valB'
    dependentProp: 'dependent value'


objB = 

  B with properties:

        propI: []
        propJ: []
        propA: 'valA'
        propB: 'valB'
    dependentProp: 'dependent value'
```

Finally, to handle your 'C' class, it is simply done by calling the constructor of the 'B' class, without adding any additional code:

```
classdef C < B
    properties
        propM
        propN
    end
    methods
        function obj=C(varargin)
            obj@B(varargin{:});
        end
    end
end
```

Then, you may create and object of class 'C' from an object of class 'B', by only copying values from class 'A':

```
objC=C(objB)
```

Which produces the desired result:

```
objC = 

  C with properties:

            propM: []
            propN: []
            propI: []
            propJ: []
            propA: 'valA'
            propB: 'valB'
    dependentProp: 'dependent value'
```

However, if class 'C' is a subclass of 'A' and NOT a subclass of 'B' (as in the OP), then it should be defined as

```
classdef C2 < A
    properties
        propM
        propN
    end
    methods
        function obj=C2(varargin)
            obj@A();
            if nargin==1
                if isa(varargin{1},'B')
                    meta=?A;
                    dependent=[meta.PropertyList.Dependent];
                    props={meta.PropertyList.Name};
                    for pname=props(~dependent)
                        eval(['obj.' pname{1} '=varargin{1}.' pname{1} ';']);
                    end
                end
            end
        end
    end
end
```

Then,

```
objC2=C2(objB)
```

will result in

```
objC2 = 

  C2 with properties:

            propM: []
            propN: []
            propA: 'valA'
            propB: 'valB'
    dependentProp: 'dependent value'
```

Let me know if this worked for you.

NOTE: If you have properties with disabled set methods in your superclass, you may have to update the constructor to exclude those from the properties being set.

ALSO NOTE: If you have set methods for your dependent variables in the superclass and need them to be set in the constructor, you'll have to address that as well.